# Re-add Netlify deploy key to Github

Tags: cms, github, deployment, git, netlify

I deauthorized Netlify from my Github but re-authorized it again. How can I get the Netlify deploy key so that I can re-add it to my Github repo? It was auto removed when i deauthorized Netlify.

Comment: On the surface this looks like it is not related to running a website, but I looked up "Netify" and it is a static website CMS that uses Git as its data store: https://www.netlifycms.org/

Comment: It's actually this: https://www.netlify.com/

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @ManmeetGill yes I did, see answer

Comment: There's an alternative answer that I got from support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions depending on your urgency:

1. Create a new site on Netlify (or delete and recreate your old one) and link it to Github again.
2. Email Netlify support to get the deploy key to add back to your Github.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just edit your current site and change the origin, and link it to your GitHub account again.

Comment: [Here is the solution to connect a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677269/netlify-deploy-failed-git-ref-refs-heads-master-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-ha?answertab=active#tab-top) on an existing site.